# How to list files content diffs for particular TFS changeset via command line?

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

Changeset consists from files (let's consider only file changes, adding, removing). I want specify changeset number and obtain **text output** with all files modifications against **previous** version **similar to TF difference** command:

```
full file name 1
....
line 1;
- old line;
+ new line;
line 3;
....
full file name 2
....
line 1;
- old line;
+ new line;
line 3;
....
```

I don't want restrict directory scope. How to list such diffs for concrete changeset in command line?

Comment: this works on small test project: "tf difference $/TeamProjectRoot /version:C4~C5 /noprompt /r". But on real project it is so slow that I was waiting for a whole day and didn't encountered any useful output - only empty directories (I compared from root of team project):

Comment: Maybe there are no changes. You can view the history in soucre control explorer. Double check the difference between the two changeset of the project. Or you can try to define a specific file (ex. xx.sln) which  has obviously changed under the projcet during two versions.

Comment: There were changes - rerun was successful. I run several diffs concurrently. I obtained 3 kinds of output 1) normal with proper changes 2) zero length files 3) files of equal size with all directories listed recursively - but with no changes. The problem was insufficient disk space for TFS temp files. Console has errors but files (I redirected output to) have no errors. So, the command is correct but performance is slow. **It seems that all work is performed on client side**. On first stage (during several hours) processors load is 100%; after that network traffic increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tf difference $/TeamProjectRoot /version:C4~C5 /noprompt /r
```

when we want to list diffs for the whole project tree for changeset 5.